# Mongo Aggregate - Get count of how many times multiple values appear in query results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm attempting to count the number of times two separate fields are true. I have two values "clickedWouldRecommend" and "clickedWouldNotRecommend". These values are defaulted too FALSE. When a button is clicked in the interface, they are set too TRUE. I'm trying to see how many clickedWouldRecommend = true and how many clickedWouldNotRecommend = true for each branch.name.

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        'branch.org_id': '100000'
      },
      { "analytics.clickedWouldRecommend": true },
      // Add OR statement to include analytics.clickedWouldNotRecommend = true?
    ]
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$branch.name',
    wouldRecommend: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
])
```

This provides results similar to:

```
 {
  "_id": [ 'Clinic Name' ],
   "wouldRecommend": 115.0
 }
```

I need to modify the query to also look for cases where analytics.clickedWouldNotRecommend is set to true. I'm trying to get output similar to this ( also notice removing the array from _id if possible ):

```
 {
  "name": 'Clinic Name'
   "wouldRecommend": 115,
   "wouldNotRecommend": 10
 },
 {
  "name": 'Second Clinic Name'
   "wouldRecommend": 200,
   "wouldNotRecommend": 12
 }
```

Here is the truncated model / schema:

```
      {
  branch: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      clinic_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      org_id: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  analytics: {
    clickedWouldRecommend: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    clickedWouldNotRecommend: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
};
```

Comment: Why you are not doing two simple count queries to get the different counts? And what is the purpose of doing this `_id: '$branch.name',`? I do not get the question.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet - There are different branches assigned to each org. I need to find out the total number of recommends and would not recommends for each Branch under a specific org. Example, i specify an org_id and there will be various branch_id's assigned under one org. So I will get output for each branch with their corresponding wouldRecommend and wouldNotRecommend totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregations

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "branch.org_id": "100000" }},
  { "$unwind": "$branch" },
  { "$facet": {
    "wouldRecommend": [
      { "$match": { "analytics.clickedWouldRecommend": true }},
      { "$group": { "_id": "$branch.name" }}
    ],
    "wouldNotRecommend": [
      { "$match": { "analytics.clickedWouldNotRecommend": true }},
      { "$group": { "_id": "$branch.name" }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

Or

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "branch.org_id": "100000" }},
  { "$unwind": "$branch" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$branch.name",
    "wouldRecommend": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$analytics.clickedWouldRecommend", true] }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "wouldNotRecommend": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$analytics.clickedWouldRecommend", true]}, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```